# Create a passwordless secondary ssh key for setting up a ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, public-key, tunnel

I need to create a script that automatically setup a ssh tunnel. I think that a dedicated ssh key without password is a good start but I couldn't find if this is possible and how to do it. 
This key should have limited privileges (only set the tunnel up) but I need another private key (with a password) for myself.

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer.

First, `ssh-keygen -f theNewPrivateKey`  otherwise it will overwrite the old private key.
Second, `ssh -i theNewPrivateKey me@mycomputer` the `-i` option changes the private key used for the authentication.

Now I can try my script.

---

Edit: how does my new key has limited privileges:

When copying the public key to $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys2 file of the target computer, I added this:

```
command="sleep 99999999999" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MA...
(+ the rest of the key)
```

Then the only command allowed is to wait forever. 
Since the purpose of creating this key was to create a reverse ssh tunnel this should be fine. 
I then create the tunnel:

```
ssh -T -R 7878:localhost:22 -i .ssh/mynewkey  me@myhomecomputer
```

Finally I can log from my home computer:

```
ssh myworklogin@localhost -p7878
```

I hope that this does not have security issues. If this is a bad thing, please let me know !

Comment: How would that new key "have limited privileges"?

Comment: Because it can do only one thing, `sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the

`ssh-keygen`

command.

Comment: Don't forget the -f option or this will overwrite the old private key

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where i had to synch a server content automatically without having to proivide the password in my robocopy script.

This [Link](http://kerneltrap.org/node/8178) helped me.